# Yahoo contact export using Yahoo contact API

Tags: php, export, contacts, yahoo-api

I download yahoo sdk from this link and and implement in my server 25th june it worked fine but today when i trying to export contact data using

https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php5

```
$profile  = $oauthapp->getProfile();
print_r($profile); // It Return valid result
```

but.

```
$con = $oauthapp->getContacts(null, 0, 1000);
var_dump($con); // But this function return false
```

my link

http://sakuti.yiipro.com/y/examples/simpleauth/simpleauth.php